# How to contain the width of the main component in Material UI Drawer component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use a Drawer in Material UI.

I want the width of the main div to take up whatever available space is left in the viewport after the menu drawer has used its space.

This is my component. I've tried setting width to auto and inherit on the content class, but it doesn't change anything.

I want the main div (where the content for a list item in the drawer) is rendered, to take only as much space is available without scrolling horizontally.

This code sandbox shows the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-tab-scrolling-h13pi?file=/test.jsx

```
import React, {  useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container'

import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import PaletteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Palette';
import CenterFocusWeakIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CenterFocusWeak';
import RoomServiceIcon from '@material-ui/icons/RoomService';
import StorefrontIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Storefront';
import AssignmentIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Assignment';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import AccountBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountBox';
import ContactSupportIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ContactSupport';
import BookIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Book';
import TuneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Tune';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import DashboardFooter from "./DashboardFooter";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9) + 1,
    },
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    // autoWidth: false
    
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
  },
}));

export default function MiniDrawer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
 //   const { performingAction, user, userData, roles } = this.props;

  
  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
 
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open,
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
              [classes.hide]: open,
            })}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            {process.env.REACT_APP_TITLE}
            
          </Typography>
            
          <IconButton color="inherit"><CloseIcon /></IconButton>    
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Drawer
            variant="permanent"
            className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
            })}
            classes={{
            paper: clsx({
                [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
                [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
            }),
            }}
        >
            <div className={classes.toolbar}>
            <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
            </IconButton>
            </div>
            
            <List>
            
                <ListItem button key="1" component={Link} to={"/DSM" }>
                    <ListItemIcon><PaletteIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary="DS"></ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="2" component={Link} to={"/MMM" }>
                    <ListItemIcon><CenterFocusWeakIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText>MM</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="3" component={Link} to={"/RCM" }>
                    <ListItemIcon><StorefrontIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText>Centre</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="4" component={Link} to={"/TT" }>
                    <ListItemIcon><AssignmentIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText>TT</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                <ListItem button key="5"  component={Link} to={"/Profile" }>
                <ListItemIcon> <AccountBoxIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>Profile</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="6"  component={Link} to={"/Account" }>
                <ListItemIcon> <SettingsIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>Account</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="7"  component={Link} to={"/Mail" }>
                <ListItemIcon> <MailIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>Mail</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="8"  component={Link} to={"/Notifications" }>
                <ListItemIcon> <NotificationsIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>Notifications</ListItemText>
                </ListItem>
            
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                
                <ListItem button key="9"  component={Link} to={"/CM" }>
                    <ListItemIcon> <BookIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText>Centre</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="10"  component={Link} to={"/DCM" }>
                    <ListItemIcon><RoomServiceIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText>Desk</ListItemText> 
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button key="11"  component={Link} to={"/Support" }>
                <ListItemIcon> <ContactSupportIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>Help and Support</ListItemText>
                </ListItem>
            
            
            </List>
        </Drawer>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />

            <Switch>
                <Route path="/DCM" component={""} />
                <Route path="/MMM" render={() => <div>Page mm</div>} />
            </Switch>
            <DashboardFooter />
        </main>
     </BrowserRouter>   
     
    </div>
      
      
  );
}
```

Comment: i put your code in codesandbox (except DashboardFooter) and i don't see any issue...i.e. no horizontal scroll or anything.... can u share some screenshot ... also DashboardFooter code if applicable... if u can put ur code in codesandbox and share the link - even better

Comment: This code sandbox shows the scrolling. I can't find the attribute that extends the width of the main container to go beyond the viewport width: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-tab-scrolling-h13pi?file=/test.jsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is the following in dash.jsx:

```
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
```

This is somehow defeating the mechanism in `Tabs` for its "scrollable tabs" functionality and results in the `Tabs` taking up as much width as is needed to display all of its tab buttons instead of showing scroll buttons. `display: 'flex'` makes it a little easier to manage the content width (such that it automatically adjusts based on the drawer width), but it isn't difficult to manage this in other ways.

## Alternative 1

In my modified version of your sandbox, to remediate the effects of removing `display: 'flex'` from the root, I'm adding padding-left to the content with the same width as the drawer:

```
  content: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(9) + 1
    }
  },
  contentDrawerOpen: {
    paddingLeft: drawerWidth
  },
...
<main className={clsx(classes.content, {[classes.contentDrawerOpen]: open})}>
```

[image: Edit Material tab scrolling]

---

## Alternative 2

Another alternative is to leave `display: 'flex'`, but specify the `max-width` appropriately on the content.

```
  content: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    maxWidth: `calc(100vw - ${theme.spacing(7) + 1}px)`,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      maxWidth: `calc(100vw - ${theme.spacing(9) + 1}px)`
    }
  },
  contentDrawerOpen: {
    maxWidth: `calc(100vw - ${drawerWidth}px)`
  },
```

[image: Edit Material tab scrolling]

---

## Alternative 3 (inspired by Ahmed Mokhtar's answer)

It also appears to be sufficient to just add `overflow: "auto"` to the `content` class for the `<main>` element:

```
  content: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    overflow: "auto"
  },
```

[image: Edit Material tab scrolling]

This last alternative is definitely the simplest.

Comment: Thank you. I need to wait 12 more hours before I can send the points to you.

Comment: I fixed it using the second method as well but then I found out that only adding `overflow: auto` to the container works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I had this problem as well and I added overflow: auto to the container and this solved it.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed that by adding `overflow: auto` to `main` which I changed to use the `Container` component:

```
container: {
  overflow: "auto"
}

{/* I added overflow: auto to this container*/}
<Container
  component="main"
  maxWidth={false}
  className={classes.container}
>
  <div className={classes.toolbar} />

  <Switch>
    <Route path="/dash" component={Dash} />
    <Route path="/MatchmakerMenu" component={Dash} />
  </Switch>
</Container>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-tab-scrolling-hqdvs?file=/dash.jsx:5032-5079)

Comment: Just adding `overflow: "auto"` to the class already on the `<main>` element appears to be sufficient (no need for the `Container` component).

Comment: I know I just wanted to show that a fluid `Container` component already exists with the ability to define `maxWidth` property to `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl` or `false`.

Comment: Awesome! I was having trouble getting Plotly resize to trigger because the parent div was not shrinking but  overflow: "auto" on the content class resolved it.